# 2 coil latching relay IC control: part number or type of IC

Tags: latching-relay

[image]

I got a wall switch for a water heater from a Chinese supplier.

In the power board they used 2 latching relays with two coils for each others.

I want to redesign this board for my DIY project. 
Here is the schematic for the driver IC controlling the two relays.
I don't know what the IC or MCU is - there's nothing written on it. It's has 8 pins, SOIC 8 package.

It receives a logic TTL input at pin 3.

If the input is high level --> Generate 100ms pulse at pin 5.

When input is low level --> Generate 100ms pulse at pin 7.

Does anyone know what kind of IC or MCU this is?

[image]

Comment: Bad drawing? That is one of the clearest hand-drawn diagrams I have seen on here, well done.

Comment: Nothing written on the IC?

Comment: Thank you. Have you ever seen this kind of ic before?

Comment: Yes, Rohat. It's totally nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't put time/effort searching what IC it is. It likely easier to find a 8 or 6 pin uP and program the same functionality in it

Comment: Cause i already have my own control board. I just wanna make a power board only. And dont wanna write a new firmware. I see this board and wonder what type of this IC is? If its a logic IC, i'll choose it but if its a MCU i'll find another solution. Thanks!

Comment: have you got the chip part number yet? Can you share the chip information with me? because of I looking this kind solution also? Thanks.